# how to add for loop inside the function in javascript?

Tags: javascript, sum

I woul like to add for loop inside the function.
I would like to appear final rating that are not completely fill of each textboxes. 
Example if I place only 80 in first grading,automatically appear the final rating.

How can do that ?

HTML Code

```
 <table  border="0" class="table table-bordered" >
  <tbody>
   <tr class="bg-primary">
    <th rowspan="2">LEARNING AREAS</th>
    <th colspan="4">Periodic Rating</th>
    <th colspan="2">FINAL RATING</th>
    <th rowspan="2">REMARKS</th>
   </tr>
   <tr align="center" class="bg-primary">
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>DES</td>
    <td>NUM</td>
   </tr>
  <tr>
     <td>Filipino</td>
     <td align='center'><input class="text" size="10" type="number" min="65" max="100" name="Filipino13" id="fil13" oninput="sum38();" onkeyup="average4();" value="<?php echo $filipino13;?>"></td>
     <td align='center'><input class="text" size="10" type="number" min="65" max="100" name="Filipino14" id="fil14" oninput="sum38();" onkeyup="average4();" value="<?php echo $filipino14;?>"></td>
     <td align='center'><input class="text" size="10" type="number" min="65" max="100" name="Filipino15" id="fil15" oninput="sum38();" onkeyup="average4();" value="<?php echo $filipino15;?>"></td>
     <td align='center'><input class="text" size="10" type="number" min="65" max="100" name="Filipino16" id="fil16" oninput="sum38();" onkeyup="average4();" value="<?php echo $filipino16;?>"></td>
     <td align='center'><input class="text" size="10" type="text" name="Des_fi4" id="des29" value="<?php echo $des_fi4;?>"></td>
     <td align='center'><input class="text" size="10" type="text" name="Aver24" id="ave29" oninput="average4();" value="<?php echo $aver24;?>"></td>
     <td align='center'><input class="text" size="10" type="text" name="Remark_fi4" id="remark29" value="<?php echo $remark_fi4;?>"></td>       
   </tr>
</tbody>
```

This is code for javascript that are using function

Javascrip Code

```
function sum38() {
   var fil13 = document.getElementById('fil13').value;
   var fil14 = document.getElementById('fil14').value;
   var fil15 = document.getElementById('fil15').value;
   var fil16 = document.getElementById('fil16').value;

   var result29 = (parseInt(fil13) + parseInt(fil14) + parseInt(fil15) + parseInt(fil16)) / 4;
   var total29 = result29.toFixed(2);

   if (!isNaN(total29)) {
       document.getElementById('ave29').value = total29;

   if (result29>=75){
     document.getElementById('remark29').value = 'Passed';
   }
     else
     {
       document.getElementById('remark29').value = 'Failed';
     }           
  }
  if(result29 >= 90){
  document.getElementById('des29').value = "(A)";
  }

  else if(result29 >=85){
  document.getElementById('des29').value = "(P)";
  }

  else if(result29 >=80){
  document.getElementById('des29').value = "(AP)";
  }

  else if(result29 >=75){
  document.getElementById('des29').value = "(D)";
  }


  else if(result29 >=74){
  document.getElementById('des29').value = "(B)";
  }
  else if(result29 >=0){
  document.getElementById('des29').value = "(B)";
  }
}
```

Comment: like [documented here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to loop through it. Just store the old value in a data attribute, and every time you do an input, add the new value to the total while subtracting the old value.

```
 <td align='center'>
   <input class="filipino text" size="10" type="number" min="65" max="100" name="Filipino13" id="fil13" oninput="sum38(this);" data-old-value="<?php echo $filipino13;?>" value="<?php echo $filipino13;?>">
 </td>
```

I added class name `filipino` and `data-old-value` above, and `this` as a parameter in your `oninput` attribute. I also removed your `onkeyup` attribute.

```
function sum38(element) {
  var des29      = document.getElementById('des29');
  var remark29   = document.getElementById('remark29');
  var ave29      = document.getElementById('ave29');
  var totalValue = des29.value || 0;
  var oldValue   = element.dataset.oldValue || 0;
  var newValue   = element.value || 0;
  var numberOfGrades = document.querySelectorAll('.filipino').length;

  totalValue     = totalValue + newValue - oldValue;

  des29.value    = totalValue;
  ave29.value    = totalValue / numberOfGrades;
  remark29.value = (totalValue >= 75) ? 'Passed' : 'Failed';
}
```

I would also refactor those if statements into a new function for better readability. The des29.value row should then be something like `des29.value = calculateGrade(totalValue)` where the `calculateGrade()` function returns the correct grade.

It's not a full solution but it will get you on your way.

Comment: Now realized that des29 is the average grade and ave29 is the average number. Oh well, I still think this way is better.